# Area51: Allow following proposals in the commit phase

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment-phase, following-proposal

Some proposals in area51 are interesting enough that I want to know if they succeed and when they open, but not interesting enough to actually commit to them. It would be nice if I could follow them even in the commit phase - from what I hear, follows made prior to the commit phase remain in the commit phase, so it shouldn't be too much of a change...

Comment: does this really merit the added of complexity of having a Follow AND a Commit button? If you spend that much time on Area51 could you just remember the topic name or bookmark it? :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Shhh... Don't tell anyone, okay? This is just between you and me. Along the top of the proposal, see the 'definition' tab? Click it. But, really, shhhhh— don't... tell... anyone...

Comment: I was still getting emails from Food and Cooking even though I didn't commit to it, so yup it's working as intended ;-)